# Is there a new replacement for SHGetSpecialFolderLocation?

Tags: c++, winapi

My app is written in C++Builder for Win32. My code uses the [`SHGetSpecialFolderLocation()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/shlobj_core/nf-shlobj_core-shgetspecialfolderlocation) API to get the `CSIDL_APPDATA` and `CSIDL_MYDOCUMENTS` paths.

I noticed on Microsoft's website dated 12/04/2018 that it says:

> [SHGetSpecialFolderLocation is not supported and may be altered or unavailable in the future. Instead, use SHGetFolderLocation.]

Then for `SHGetFolderLocation` it says:

> Deprecated

What is the current way to get these two paths?

My current code is below.

```
LPITEMIDLIST List = NULL;
wchar_t  wPath[MAX_PATH + 1];
UnicodeString S01, Fi;

if( !SHGetSpecialFolderLocation(0, CSIDL_APPDATA, &List) ){
  if( SHGetPathFromIDListW(List, wPath ) ){
    S01 = wPath;
    Fi = (S01+"\\my_files\\");
    Form1->MyRoamingPath_Mh = Fi;
  }
}
```

Comment: It is as if they are depreciating CSIDL and replacing with GUIDs as KNOWNFOLDERID. It would be worth asking on the Developer Network as it is not obvious through the links.

Comment: Seems [`SHGetKnownFolderPath`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/shlobj_core/nf-shlobj_core-shgetknownfolderpath) is the *currently* preferred way of getting special directories. For now.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[`SHGetSpecialFolderLocation()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/shlobj_core/nf-shlobj_core-shgetspecialfolderlocation) was first introduced in Windws 95/NT4.  It was deprecated in Windows 2000/XP in favor of [`SHGetFolderLocation()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/shlobj_core/nf-shlobj_core-shgetfolderlocation) (which returns a folder location as an `IDLIST_ABSOLUTE`) and [`SHGetFolderPath()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/shlobj_core/nf-shlobj_core-shgetfolderpathw) (which returns a folder location as a path string).

So, in your example, you could have used `SHGetFolderPath()` instead:

```
#include <Shlobj.h>
#include <SysUtils.hpp>

wchar_t wPath[MAX_PATH + 1];

if (SHGetFolderPathW(NULL, CSIDL_APPDATA, NULL, SHGFP_TYPE_CURRENT, wPath) == S_OK)
{
    Form1->MyRoamingPath_Mh = IncludeTrailingPathDelimiter(wPath) + L"my_files\\";
}
```

In Vista, use of [`CSIDL`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/shell/csidl) was deprecated in favor of [`KNOWNFOLDERID`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/shell/knownfolderid).  The above functions have been deprecated in favor of [`SHGetKnownFolderIDList()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/shlobj_core/nf-shlobj_core-shgetknownfolderidlist)/[`IKnownFolder::GetIDList()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/shobjidl_core/nf-shobjidl_core-iknownfolder-getidlist) and [`SHGetKnownFolderPath()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/shlobj_core/nf-shlobj_core-shgetknownfolderpath)/[`IKnownFolder::GetPath()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/shobjidl_core/nf-shobjidl_core-iknownfolder-getpath), respectively.

This is actually stated at the *bottom* of the `SHGetFolderLocation()` documentation <sup>1</sup>:

<sup>1: I guess you did not scroll down far enough to see it.</sup>

> **Note** As of Windows Vista, this function is merely a wrapper for `SHGetKnownFolderIDList`. The `CSIDL` value is translated to its associated `KNOWNFOLDERID` and `SHGetKnownFolderIDList` is called. **New applications should use the known folder system rather than the older `CSIDL` system, which is supported only for backward compatibility**.

So, in your example, you can now use `SHGetKnownFolderPath()` instead:

```
#include <Shlobj.h>
#include <SysUtils.hpp>

PWSTR pwPath;

if (SHGetKnownFolderPath(FOLDERID_RoamingAppData, KF_FLAG_DEFAULT, NULL, &pwPath) == S_OK)
{
    try
    {
        Form1->MyRoamingPath_Mh = IncludeTrailingPathDelimiter(pwPath) + L"my_files\\";
    }
    __finally
    {
        CoTaskMemFree(pwPath);
    }
}
```

For the "My Documents" folder, use `FOLDERID_Documents`.

Comment: As a side note the values FOLDERID_Documents and CSIDL_MYDOCUMENTS now return a path for Microsoft OneDrive documents folder User\OneDrive\Documents. Previously it returned the local users document folder User\Documents.

Comment: @homebase Not by default, they don't. `CSIDL_MYDOCUMENTS` and `FOLDERID_Documents` map to the user's local profile by default, always have, always will. There is a new `KNOWNFOLDERID` specifically for OneDrive: `FOLDERID_SkyDriveDocuments`. But, Known Folder locations can be redirected to new locations, and the OneDrive client does redirect `FOLDERID_Documents` if you allow it to auto-save documents to OneDrive.